I have issues running test on my pom.xml in my app it says org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:${spring.boot.version}
i keep getting these 2 errors in my pom.xml file
1 is  : Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:${spring.boot.version}
2nd is : Error resolving version for plugin 'org.spring.framework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin' from the repositories [local (C:\Users\admin.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
my code looks like this

4.0.0
<groupId>org.springframework.samples.petclinic.client</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-petclinic-customers-service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>2.1.2</version>
<description>Spring PetClinic Customers Service</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-petclinic-microservices</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <docker.image.exposed.port>8081</docker.image.exposed.port>
    <docker.image.dockerfile.dir>${basedir}/../docker</docker.image.dockerfile.dir>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Third parties -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>buildDocker</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${docker.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

i need help resolving these errors

You are missing a version for your spring-boot-maven-plugin. You can find the available versions in here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin
You also don't have a property set for spring.boot.version.
If you set that in your properties to a valid version then that should resolve your problems

The normal declaration of dependencies typically has 3 fields:, e.g.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

You are simply missing version numbers.  In some cases you can avoid them if you use a Bill of Materials (bom), but just for now, I suggest you declare in the existing <properties> node something like this:
  <spring-boot.version>2.7.18</spring-boot.version>

And then reference this in each of the Spring dependencies, e.g.
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

repeating for all your Spring artifacts.
Then repeats for each artifact for mysql, etc.  Sometimes other dependencies are nominating versions and so you can let those dependencies decide for you.
If you are looking to find out what versions are available look at https://mvnrepository.com/ Of course, some of your dependencies may require particular versions of other dependencies...
